# API level of 28 in android studio and latest sdk-version is 26.0.0-alpha1 in appcompat-v7 folder

Tags: java, android

I don't get any error while gradle build but my MainActivity shows error across every AppCompatActivity related terms.[image]

I noticed at the location of android-sdk the appcompat-v7 folder has till 26.0.0-alpha-1 only but I'm using API 28

Tried Every solution out there even tried reinstalling didn't help.
Yes going to previous versions is helping but why I won't be able to use API 28.

Comment: See those red 3 dots after the word import that means you are importing something wrong. Expand that see the import statement that is the problem then re import it. As to the API level you need to update your build tools search for sdk manager and make sure your packages are up to date under SDK Tools tab, and make sure you set the right version in gradle too or delete the line with buildToolVersion entirely and android studio should automatically import the wright one.

Comment: @Mihai done everything. problem still persists for me

Answer (score -1):

> add this line in gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

and change project settings to latest 4.4

Comment: also project settings is set to latest 4.4 by default